# JS RegEx for finding number of lines in a page, separated by form feed \f

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a use case that requires a plain-text file to have lines to consist of at most 38 characters, and 'pages' to consist of at most 28 lines. To enforce this, I'm using regular expressions. I was able to enforce the line-length without any problems, but the page-length is proving to be much trickier.
After several iterations, I came to the following as a regular expression that I feel should work, but it isn't.

```
let expression = /(([^\f]*)(\r\n)){29,}\f/;
```

It simply results in no matches.

If anyone could provide some feedback, I'd greatly appreciate it! - Jacob

Edit 1 - removed code block around second expression, it was probably making my question confusing.

Edit 2 - removed following text, it's not pertinent:
As a comparison, the following expression results in a single match, the entire document. I'm assuming it's matching all lines up until the final
let expression = /(.*(\r\n)){29,}

Edit 3 - So after some thinking, I realized that my issue is due to the initial section of the regex that matches any characters before a newline is including newlines. Therefore, I believe I need to match any characters before a newline EXCEPT (\f\r\n). However, I'm now having trouble implementing this. I tried the following:

`let expression = /([^\f^\r^\n]*(\r\n)){29,}\f/;`

But it's also not matching. I'm assuming that my negations are wrong...

Edit 4 - I have the following regex that matches each line: `let expression = /([^\f\r\n]{0,}(\r\n))/;`
This is pretty close to what I want. All I need now is to match any instances of 29 or more lines followed by \f

Comment: This part `(.*(\r\n)){29,}` repeats 29 or more times so that is why you get the whole document if there are more than 28 lines followed by a newline. What do you want to accomplish? You want to make sure that is it exactly 28 lines?

Comment: I understand why the second expression is failing, but the first is where I think it should work. It should be 29 or more times followed by a \f, and each instance of a match should be separated by \f. The \f is key.

Comment: You get a single match because you repeat the pattern 29 or more times using a quantifier and matching the whole line including newlines. If you use `{29}` instead you get 29 lines.

Comment: Yes @Thefourthbird, you are correct. It's because I'm matching the new lines. I realize now that I need to exclude newlines from the initial * times, but I'm having trouble with this implementation...

Comment: If you want all the separate lines, you could also split the complete match on a newline. Or first check the number of the lines, and if that is correct, then match each line separately using `.*` for example.

Comment: I was able to get a match on a single line excluding \f\r\n ending with \r\n, but I'm having trouble getting a specific number of lines to match now, before even introducing the terminating \f. If I look for any specific number of lines, such as {2}, it results in no matches at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

As you clarified more your problem, and provided your updated regex:

```
/([^\f^\r^\n]*(\r\n)){29,}\f/;
```

Your negations are not right here, use `[^\f\r\n]` instead of `[^\f^\r^\n]`. This will negate all of `\f`, `\r`, and `\n`.

So, your regex becomes:

```
/([^\f\r\n]*(\r\n)){29,}\f/;
```

This will match 29 or more lines of characters (that can be anything but `\f`, `\r` or `\n`), the whole thing followed by a single `\f`.

---

**Original answer:**

Your current regular expression:

```
let expression = /(([^\f]*)(\r\n)){29,}\f/;
```

Matches strings that consist of 29 or more lines (separated by `\r\n`), the whole thing followed by one single `\f`.

As far as I understood, you want each of your lines to end with `\f`. Did you mean to include the `\f` inside?

```
let expression = /(([^\f]*)(\r\n\f)){29,}/;
```

Comment: No, lines end with \r\n, I want to find blocks of text that are 29 or more lines long without being broken by a \f character.

Comment: You're right, I realized my mistake with the negation. Please see the latest Edit 4. I was able to get a match on a single line excluding \f\r\n ending with \r\n, but I'm having trouble getting a specific number of lines to match now, before even introducing the terminating \f

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help to those who commented, a friend ended up helping me get the final regex

```
let expression = /([^\f\r\n]*?\r??\n){29,}?\f/;
```